# Ant throwing Configuration faliure when I try to run selenium script

Tags: selenium, ant

I got the following error when I tried to run selenium testng script from ant cmd prompt. The script started, but failed from where the webdriver code started.This script runs fine when I run it from eclipse.

```
 [testng] [TestNG] Running:
 [testng]   C:\workspace\AntDemo\testng.xml
 [testng]
 [testng]  INFO [main] (TestHomePage.java:27)- Init Started
 [testng]
 [testng] ===============================================
 [testng] Suite
 [testng] Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
 [testng] Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
 [testng] ===============================================
 [testng]
 [testng] The tests failed.
```

I am giving a sample of the build file that I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE project [
]>

<project name="Selenium" default="usage" basedir=".">

<!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->

<property environment="env"/>

<property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}"/>

<property name="ws.jars" value="C:\Jars"/>

<property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>

<property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>

<property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>

<!--target name="start-selenium-server">

<java jar="${ws.home}/lib/selenium-server.jar"/>

</target-->

<target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">

<path id="classpath_jars">

<fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>

</path>

<pathconvert pathsep=":"

property="test.classpath"

refid="classpath_jars"/>

</target>

<target name="init" depends="setClassPath">

<tstamp>

<format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />

</tstamp>

<condition property="ANT"

value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat"

else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">

<os family="windows" />

</condition>

<taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"

classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />

</target>

<!-- all -->

<target name="all">

</target>

<!-- clean -->

<target name="clean">

<delete dir="${test.dest}"/>

</target>

<!-- compile -->

<target name="compile" depends="init, clean" >

<delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">

<fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>

</delete>

<echo message="making directory..."/>

<mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>

<echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}"/>

<echo message="compiling..."/>

<javac debug="true" destdir="${test.dest}" srcdir="${test.src}" target="1.5" classpath="${test.classpath}"
>

</javac>

</target>

<!-- build -->

<target name="build" depends="init">

</target>

<!-- run -->

<target name="run" depends="compile">

<testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="suite1">

<xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml"/>

</testng>

</target>

<target name="usage">

<echo>

ant run will execute the test

</echo>

</target>

<path id="test.c">

<fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar"/>

</path>

<target name="makexsltreports">

<mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

<xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml" style="src/xslt/testng-results.xsl"

out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" classpathref="test.c" processor="SaxonLiaison">

<param name="testNgXslt.outputDir" expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/"/>

<param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true"/>

</xslt>

</target>

<!-- ****************** targets not used ****************** -->

</project>
```

Is there something that I am missing in the build file?
Please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: C:\Jars contains selenium jar?

Comment: Yes. Selenium, testng, log4j jars

Comment: Can you try running ant script in debug mode and see the details.

Comment: This issue is resolved. I figured out that I had kept the wrong selenium jar file in the jars folder. Thank you for your inputs.